# Upgrading Nginx to 1.4

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Are there any recent breaking changes between different NGINX versions I should be aware of if I want to update to 1.4?

I was thinking of upgrading NGINX on our Ubuntu 10.04 production server to 1.4 to support the new SPDY protocol. Checking my current version of NGINX is 0.7.65.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx 1.4 is for Windows and for Linux latest stable is Nginx- 1.2.8 , they have maintain a nice change log with Version you can go through it and then take call

```
  http://nginx.org/en/CHANGES-1.2
```

I believe there will be no problem you can upgrade you NGINX and it is good practice to keep Web Server and other package uptodate.

Comment: I did the jump and made it didn't crash my production server, so I guess I get to keep my job... As a note to other Ubuntu 10.04 users you might need to follow this guide to update like I did. http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?11,225513,225930